# How to use an Azure Arm Template Output in a variable?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to solve a problem I'm having with an Azure ARM template, whereby I need to capture the output of a queried resource in my ARM template, then in that same template, feed that output into a variable / inject that output into a script on another resource that depends on it.

An example -

```
   "outputs":{
      "downloadLocation": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('randomResource', variables('ResourceName'))).downloadLocation]"
      }
   }
```

And

```
variables: {
    "downloadLocation": "[outputs('downloadLocation')]"
}
```

This variable is then referenced in one of the resources that depends on the source of the queried output.

The downloadLocation can't be formatted in anyway, it contains several signatures and unpredictable strings.

FYI - the below code stops the arm template from being used, by producing the error 'The template function 'outputs' is not valid.'

I'm not locked to storing it as an output, I just need to be able to use that value in another resource - however it's achieved!

The only other route I know would work, but I don't want to explore yet, is that the output could be stored in a file somewhere, then a subsequent script picks it up and injects it into a second ARM template.

If there is a way to use this please let me know, it would help me out significantly!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.
The reference function can be called when inside a resource field. So I've had to use reference function as seen above, but it can't be stored in a variable or parameter, it instead needs to be called directly in the resource that's requiring it. Which in this case was the osProfile - customData field.